# Holomorphic function on unit disk and 1

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $B$, where  $B=D\cup \{1\},  D=\{z: |z|<1\}$.
$f(D)\subset D, f(1)=1$.  prove that $f'(1)\geq 0$

Comment: Since $1$ is not in the interior of $B$, how do you define $f$ holomorphic on $B$. In particular, what does $f'(1)$ mean?

Comment: It is customary to also include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Extending julien's question, do you mean that $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $B$, or is $f'(1)$ defined as $\lim\limits_{z\to 1,z\in D}\dfrac{f(z)-f(1)}{z-1}$?

Comment: @julien: The **standard** usage when blah is not open is to say that $f$ is holomorphic on blah iff for every point $x$ of blah there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and a holomorphic function $g$ on $V$ that coincides with $f$ on $V\cap$blah. Here, this just means that there is an open set containing $D\cup B$ where $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo Well, it was not standard (I don't know how to make it bold) for Jonas and me. I've mostly seen people say holomorphic on an open neighborhood of $B$ in such a case. Thanks, for clarifying, not sure about what you meant by using bold characters, though.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. For the statement to be true, one only need $f$ to be complex differentiable at $1$. No need to assume $f$ can be extendable to some neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: Hint: if $f'(1) = |f'(1)| e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \ne 0$, say $\theta > 0$, what will happen to the image of the curve $t \mapsto 1+ t e^{i\phi}$ under $f$ when $\phi \in (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Could you elaborate, Achille?